# Where can I find good documentation on "msconfig" and "services.msc" for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, boot, services, process, msconfig

Running Windows 7

I'm trying to boost the startup speed of my computer and I'm going through "msconfig" and "services.msc" to disable some applications from starting up automatically when the computer turns on.

There are some good sites that document the entries found in the "Processes" tab of the task manager.  You can find out if they are safe to kill, who the manufacturer is, and what the process in question is used  for.

Are there any sites that list startup processes &| services that are safe to kill?  For example, there is an entry in msconfig that just says "Computer Browser" - pretty vague, but seems like something to not kill.  On the other hand, there is an entry in msconfig that says "Extensible Authentication Protocol" - pretty specific and seems like it shouldn't be killed, but how can I know for sure?

Does anyone know if there are any websites documenting the "killable" items listed in both msconfig & services.msc?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a website but will give a light description of all processes ( like Computer Browser )

Administrator tools - Component services - local services. highlight and it gives a light description.

[image: Component services image]

- More information on [Svhost.exe](http://svchost-exe.net/)
- Mre information  [Common Windows processes](http://www.neuber.com/taskmanager/process/index.html)

Generally I would say leave the ms installs and start with the 3rd party starts.
Glarys [free it has a start manager,](http://www.glarysoft.com/)
Highlight the programs to find information, then click on 'more information' at the bottom to get community opinions on the related software.

[CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/CCLEANER) is also very good and provides helpful information.

The Windows[System Configuration page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Using-System-Configuration)

Windows 7 [Ultimate Tweaks & Utilities](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?63273)

Hope you find what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

[BlackViper has the very best settings](http://www.blackviper.com/2010/12/17/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/) for Services in Windows 7, full explanations also.